# Does the autofocus form attribute violate accessibility standards?

Tags: accessibility, autofocus

I am wondering if the `autofocus` form attribute violates accessibility standards. Is there a cited authoritative precedent for that?

Comment: I don't think so because accessibility standards are so complex and a screen reader/helper may ignore reorganize your design if it's always bad for the user. It's maybe a better question for  https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If used judiciously, it does not violate accessibility standards.

The one scenario where I have seen it cause a confusing loss of focus problem that violated WCAG 3.2.2 http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/#consistent-behavior is in Safari on OS X, where the autofocus input was part of a constantly updating Angular.js application. In this scenario, Safari will continue to grab the focus into the autofocus input, when the area was updated, causing focus loss.

You can read about how I addressed that here http://unobfuscated.blogspot.com/2015/01/angular-accessibility-issues-focus.html